# Compressing the primes using simple addition?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, integers, additive-combinatorics, compression

Consider the sets of integers
$$
A = \{1, 3, 7, 13, 27\} \\
B = \{4, 10, 16, 40, 100\} 
$$

**Elementwise addition** of sets $A, B$ looks like $A + B := \{ a + b: a \in A, b \in B\}$.

Now elementwise-add them to form $A + B$.  Here is the result:
$$
\begin{matrix}
+ & 1 & 3 & 7 & 13 & 27 & \\
4 & 5 & 7 & 11 & 17 & 31 & \\
10 & 11 & 13 & 17 & 23 & 37 \\
16 & 17 & 19 & 23 & 29 & 43 \\
40 & 41 & 43 & 47 & 53 & 67  \\
100 & 101 & 103 & 107 & 113 & 127\\
\end{matrix}
$$

As you can see, this doesn't perfectly list the first $n$ primes since $59$ is missing.

Can you come up with two sets of integers $A, B$ such that $A + B$ consists only of prime numbers and such that $|A + B| \gt 20$.  In other words, can you beat me in my example above?

Thus, if we don't examine the size of the integers involved in the above matrix, we've effectly compressed $n^2 - n$ primes into $2n$ numbers where $n = 5$.  I don't know about you, but to me that seems pretty darn interesting!

---

Continuing from above (by pen & paper):
$$
\begin{matrix}
+ & 1 & 3 & 7 & 13 & 27 & 57 &\\
4 & 5 & 7 & 11 & 17 & 31 & 61\\
10 & 11 & 13 & 17 & 23 & 37 & 67\\
16 & 17 & 19 & 23 & 29 & 43 & 73\\
40 & 41 & 43 & 47 & 53 & 67 & 97\\
100 & 101 & 103 & 107 & 113 & 127 & 157\\
\end{matrix}
$$

---

Here's a script you can play with:

```
from sympy.ntheory import prime, isprime

# Seed with whatever you want:
A = [1, 3, 7]
B = [4, 10, 16]

M = 1000

for k in range(0, M):
    if k % 2 == 0:
        b = max(B) + 1
        for n in range(b, b + M):
            for a in A:
                if not isprime(a + n):
                    break
            else:
                B.append(n)
                break
    else:
        a = max(A) + 1
        for n in range(a, a + M):
            for b in B:
                if not isprime(b + n):
                    break
            else:
                A.append(n)
                break


def elementwise_add(A, B):
    C = set()
    for a in A:
        for b in B:
            C.add(a + b)
    return list(C)

print(A)
print(B)
C = elementwise_add(A, B)
C.sort()
print(C)
```

### Outputs:

```
[1, 3, 7, 13, 27, 63, 97]
[4, 10, 16, 40, 100, 346, 1090, 1426]
[5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 67, 73, 79, 101, 103, 107, 113, 127, 137, 163, 197, 347, 349, 353, 359, 373, 409, 443, 1091, 1093, 1097, 1103, 1117, 1153, 1187, 1427, 1429, 1433, 1439, 1453, 1489, 1523]
```

---

Did some thought on the problem:

Ease the constraints some, and allow $0, \pm 1$ into the result set of $A + B$.

Take a finite subsquare of the composition group law for $(\Bbb{Z}, +)$.  For example:

$$
\begin{matrix}
-2 & (-1) & 0 & 1 & 2 & (3)  & 4 & (5) \\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & \\
0 & 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7  \\
1 & 2 & 3  & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
2 & 3  & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9  \\
3  & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10\\
4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
6 & (7) & 8 & 9 & 10 & (11) & 12 & (13) \\
\vdots \\
12 & (13) & 14 & 15 & 16 & (17) & 18 & (19) \\
\end{matrix}
$$

First, assume that $7$ is in $A$ and highlight the prime columns with parentheses like above.  Those are the only columns that you can select from to fill out $B$.  Since we don't want to delete anything from $A$, highlight all rows such that the rows prime columns contain row "7"s prime columns.  This is done in the table above.

Comment: Do you mean $|A| \cdot |B| >25$? (your example achieves product $25$ but sum only $10$)

Comment: @coffeemath you're right, that's what I mean.  Such that $|A + B| \gt 20$ (I counted them up!)

Comment: @coffeemath Oh, I see your mistake.  You're confusing $+$ with $\cup$.

Comment: Are we looking to list the first $K$ consecutive primes? Or you only care about listing some primes, regardless of their consecutivity?

Comment: @RGS either one.  Thank you

Comment: You can have A as {$1$} and B as {$p_1-1, p_2-1 \cdot\cdot\cdot p_{26}-1$} where $p_x$ is a prime, to suit your conditions. But that’s not what you’re looking for. So both sets should have absolute size of at least $2$.

Comment: Perhaps, to make this more interesting, you should require that $A$ and $B$ have the same number of elements?

Comment: It's too bad that this leads nowhere!  The primes are indeed an unsolved mystery...

Comment: Not sure if it helps but the primes are too complicated to compress. Compressing data implies " simple patterns " or " using formulas" , without that it is not possible. The primes are as complicated as the digits of $\pi$, what you can see from $\zeta(2 n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've found. I was concentrating more on keeping $\sup(A+B)$ fairly small than on maximising $|A+B|$.
\begin{array}{rrllrr}
|A|&|B|&A&B&\sup(A+B)&|A+B|\\
5&5& 5, 7, 17, 23, 37 & 0, 6, 24, 36, 66 &103& 20 \\
5&5& 7, 11, 17, 29, 31 & 0, 12, 30, 72, 120 &151& 23 \\
5&5& 11, 17, 29, 31, 37 & 0, 30, 42, 72, 120 &157& 24\\
5&5& 1, 13, 23, 31, 41 & 6, 30, 66, 126, 150 &191& 25\\ \hline
6&6& 7, 11, 17, 31, 41, 67 & 0, 6, 12, 30, 72, 96    &163& 28 \\
6&6& 5, 13, 17, 47, 73, 83 & 0, 6, 24, 54, 66, 84    &167& 29 \\
6&6& 5, 7, 17, 31, 41, 61  & 0, 6, 12, 66, 96, 132   &193& 32 \\
6&6& 1, 11, 25, 35, 41, 55 & 6, 12, 18, 72, 138, 156 &211& 33 \\
6&6& 1, 11, 31, 61, 71, 101& 12, 36, 78, 96, 162, 180&281& 34 \\ \hline
7&7& 7, 17, 23, 41, 73, 83, 101 & 0, 6, 30, 66, 90, 150, 156 &257& 35 \\ 
7&7& 1, 17, 35, 67, 77, 95, 101 & 6, 12, 36, 72, 96, 156, 162&263& 36 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Answer (score 2):

$|A|=|B|=8,\space |A+B|=64$

I have spiced it up a little bit, **numbers in each row are consecutive primes**.

\begin{matrix}
& 165523 & 165527 & 165533 & 165541 & 165551 & 165553 & 165559 & 165569 \\ 
\\
+1099560& 1265083 & 1265087 & 1265093 & 1265101 & 1265111 & 1265113 & 1265119 & 1265129 \\ 
+6067230& 6232753 & 6232757 & 6232763 & 6232771 & 6232781 & 6232783 & 6232789 & 6232799 \\ 
+16348200& 16513723 & 16513727 & 16513733 & 16513741 & 16513751 & 16513753 & 16513759 & 16513769 \\ 
+41967240& 42132763 & 42132767 & 42132773 & 42132781 & 42132791 & 42132793 & 42132799 & 42132809 \\ 
+56322420& 56487943 & 56487947 & 56487953 & 56487961 & 56487971 & 56487973 & 56487979 & 56487989 \\ 
+65835840& 66001363 & 66001367 & 66001373 & 66001381 & 66001391 & 66001393 & 66001399 & 66001409 \\
+92498820& 92664343 & 92664347 & 92664353 & 92664361 & 92664371 & 92664373 & 92664379 & 92664389 \\ 
+95634000& 95799523 & 95799527 & 95799533 & 95799541 & 95799551 & 95799553 & 95799559 & 95799569 
\end{matrix}

Comment: How did you generate this, and why did you use such big numbers?

Comment: @EnjoysMath Obviously with computer, I can post the code here if you want to play with it. This is the smallest matrix that has 9 rows made of 8 consecutive prime numbers with each row having the same prime gaps as the first one. It’s pretty amazing that all increments in the first column are divisible by 10.

Comment: Yes, pleaes post the code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example if we are only requiring $A+B$ consist of primes (and not the first $n$ primes).

Let $Q_n=\{a_1,\ldots, a_n\}$ be a set of prime numbers such that $a_i \equiv 1 \pmod {10}$ and $a_{i}+2$ is also a prime. Using a twin prime table, this is easy to obtain. For example, we can let
$$Q_{10}=\{11, 71, 101, 191, 281, 311, 431, 461, 821, 881\}.$$
Then let $A=\{1,3\}$ and $B=\{a-1: a \in Q_n\}$, and $A+B$ will consist of exactly 20 primes.

Since there are arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions of primes, theoretically one should be able to make $A$ and $B$ have any size.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is quite an old post.  With the proper seeding, one should be able to generate a nxn matrix of primes (not all distinct).  A bit much to describe here totally, but one solution that generates 164 unique primes is odds= [1,11,17,41,101,1481,3917,14627,27737,118901,111018431,574060031,47357739281]
evens=
[2,6,12,30,72,156,546,11886,78696,137436,1676610,12618762,168920413410]

I can provide the mechanism in PariGP code.  The seeding here was [1,2,6,11].

With the proper seeding, one can likely produce any size though timing really slows after ~ 10x10.